# How to access the jupyter lab in terminal on Windows?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I installed a jupyter-lab using `python3.9 -m pip install jupyterlab`

then I got the following error while running `jupyter-lab` in one of my folders(Downloads, for example):

````
jupyter : The term 'jupyter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ jupyter lab
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jupyter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: `python -m jupyterlab`

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I was just exporing around terminal and found that when I entered `python -m jupyterlab` in a specific folder. So it worked finely.